# Regroup bug and task states in task backlog board

Tags: tfs

We are using TFS 2018 Update 2 with a task backlog that is configured to display the bugs as tasks. The problem is that we have like 10 states on bugs, and the names are different of the task states, so our board has too many columns.

I thought I could regroup those columns by defining the  element under the  item that does not seem to regroup anything. We use the  element successfully on PortfolioBacklog and RequirementBacklog items, and the documentation says  is available under  so I don't really understand...

Any idea how we are supposed to manage that?